# Error: Database is locked when calling sqlite3_exec() from fork() child

Tags: c, database, sqlite, fork, blocked

I have a server/client program where the server spawns a child with fork() for each client connected. Then, client sends commands to server to execute certain queries on sqlite3 database (INSERT INTO, SELECT, DELETE FROM).
**Note:** I open the database after fork() as is specified here: https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html at **2.6**

### Problem

Works perfectly when 1 client is connected, but when there are 2 connected: when one of them executes the first query that modifies the database (ex: INSERT INTO), from that point forward only it can continue modifying. The rest of them get the **error: Database is locked**. Even after the client blocking the .db terminates, the other still can't modify.

### I have tried:

- **PRAGMA journal_mode=wal** in sqlite3 terminal
- executing manually **BEGIN TRANSACTION;** before INSERT query and **COMMIT;** after
- **sqlite3_close(db)** after INSERT query and reopening it after

#### Observation:

I know that using threads would probably be safer and would solve the problem, but I would like to have tried everything with fork() before changing the entire project structure.

#### Server code (I removed irrelevant parts of code):

```
int main () {
   sqlite3* db;
   //code for connection...
   while (1) {
        client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);
        if (-1 == (pid = fork())) {
            perror("Error at fork");
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            if (sqlite3_open("./Database.db", &db))
            perror("Error: Could not open database.\n")
            while (1) {
                sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",string1, string2,string3,string4,string5,string6);
                if(sqlite3_exec(db, query, NULL, 0, &error) != SQLITE_OK){
                      printf("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                      fflush(stdout);
                }
         }
}
```

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: `perror` is not appropriate. If `sqlite_open3` returns something other than `SQLITE_OK`, the correct error mesage can be obtained from `sqlite3_errmsg`. So, what error are you actually getting?

Comment: True, I will fix that but the db opens correctly as queries can be executed normally outside of the situation I presented

Comment: Ah, you're saying that's it's `exec` that's failing?

Comment: You really should be using a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and binding the values to be inserted to parameters in it, instead of building a string with `sprintf()` and using `sqlite3_exec()`. That's how you get sql injection attacks, mysterious syntax errors, etc.

Comment: Yes, printf("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db)) prints the error Database is locked.

Comment: Is this database by any chance on a NFS or other remote filesystem?

Comment: No, it is local.

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: @Shawn I will try that but I believe it is not the root of my problem as the queries execute just fine outside of the situation I presented.

Comment: @Shawn I am using Linux, Ubuntu

Comment: Freestanding, in a VM, etc?

Comment: @Shawn It's dual boot with windows, but I ran my code on other PCs as well, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

The problem was that the database could only communicate with one process at a time, so I opened and closed the database before and after each query and now it works perfectly.
 Only problem that could still appear now is if multiple processes run a query at the same time, but this can not happen in my program. 
 **Solution:** This can be fixed by using threads and mutex instead of fork(). 
 **Thank you for your help**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal test program that forks a bunch of child processes, of all which try to insert single rows at a time without transactions into a database. I can't replicate your results - even with no busy timeout, more than one process is able to insert at least some data (though there are a lot of lock errors in that case).

Does this give you the same behavior you're seeing when you try it?

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TRIALS 5

// The smaller the timeout, the more likely to get a locked error.
#define TIMEOUT 200

int main(void) {
  for (int n = 0; n < TRIALS; n++) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
      perror("fork");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
      sqlite3 *db;
      sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
      // test.db needs a table named test like:
      // CREATE TABLE test(a,b)
      if (sqlite3_open("test.db", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_open in child %d: %s\n", n,
                sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      sqlite3_busy_timeout(db, TIMEOUT);
      if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)", -1, &stmt,
                             NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_prepare_v2 in child %d: %s\n", n,
                sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, n);
      for (int m = 0; m < TRIALS; m++) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, m);
        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
          fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3_step in child %d: %s\n", n,
                  sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "child %d inserted %d\n", n, m);
        }
        sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        // Sleep for a short time to allow another process to run.
        // Otherwise this loop runs fast enough that it might as well
        // be done in serial, not parallel.
        unsigned int p;
        sqlite3_randomness(sizeof p, &p);
        sqlite3_sleep((p % 50) + 1);
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
      sqlite3_close(db);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  for (int n = 0; n < TRIALS; n++) {
    wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I ran your code, this is the output: (i eliminated some lines to fit in comment, but they are about 50-50% error and successful inserts)
sqlite3_step in child 1: database is locked
sqlite3_step in child 2: database is locked
sqlite3_step in child 3: database is locked
sqlite3_step in child 4: database is locked
child 0 inserted 0
child 2 inserted 1
sqlite3_step in child 3: database is locked
sqlite3_step in child 4: database is locked
sqlite3_step in child 0: database is locked
child 1 inserted 1
sqlite3_step in child 2: database is locked
child 3 inserted 2